# Sharing PCI device with 2 different PCI drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci

I am writing pci driver to access the Intel device with ID PCI_DEVICE_ID_INTEL_BROADWELL_IMC_HA0., which is at ff:12.0 (device ID 0x6fa0).

But, turned out sbridge_edac driver was already installed and associated with that PCI device.  This causes my pci_register_driver() to return error.
Is there a way to make my PCI driver use that PCI device if another driver already associated with it?

```
#define PCI_DEVICE_ID_INTEL_BROADWELL_IMC_HA0   0x6fa0

static const struct pci_device_id sbridge_pci_tbl[] = {
    {PCI_DEVICE(PCI_VENDOR_ID_INTEL, PCI_DEVICE_ID_INTEL_SBRIDGE_IMC_HA0)},
   {PCI_DEVICE(PCI_VENDOR_ID_INTEL, PCI_DEVICE_ID_INTEL_IBRIDGE_IMC_HA0_TA)},
    {PCI_DEVICE(PCI_VENDOR_ID_INTEL, PCI_DEVICE_ID_INTEL_HASWELL_IMC_HA0)},
    {PCI_DEVICE(PCI_VENDOR_ID_INTEL, PCI_DEVICE_ID_INTEL_BROADWELL_IMC_HA0)},
    {PCI_DEVICE(PCI_VENDOR_ID_INTEL, PCI_DEVICE_ID_INTEL_KNL_IMC_SAD0)},
    {0,}            /* 0 terminated list. */
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(pci, sbridge_pci_tbl);

static struct pci_driver discovery_pci_driver ={
    .name       = DRIVER_NAME,
    .probe      = discovery_probe,
    .remove     = discovery_remove,
    .id_table   = sbridge_pci_tbl,
};

static int __init discovery_init(void)
{
    int res;

    res = pci_register_driver(&discovery_pci_driver);
    if(res<0) {
        PERR("Adding driver to pci core failed\n");
       return res;
}


return 0;
}


$lspci -x

ff:12.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Home Agent 0
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v4/Xeon E5 v4/Xeon E3 v4/Xeon D Home Agent 0
    Kernel driver in use: sbridge_edac
```

Comment: It means you have either convert sbridge_edac to MFD, or extend it accordingly.

Comment: Did you mean to modify sbridge_edac? It is in upstream kernel code, which I cannot just easily change?

Comment: Yes. Why not? You have to do the driver in accordance with specification from HW vendor (Intel). So, before give you better answer you have to update a post with a link to the specification or citing necessary parts here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to create your own driver and associate it with the Intel hardware you can do one of the following:

1. Remove the `sbridge_edac` driver from the kernel config and recompile. You could also add your driver at this time.
2. Create a startup script that unloads the `sbridge_edac` driver and then loads in your driver.
3. Extend the `sbridge_edac` driver with your functionality (edit their code).
4. Create a function in your user space code that determines what driver is running and call it accordingly. You would have to put your driver functionality in your user space code and work with the `sbridge_edac`. But other user programs could access this one program instead of a driver.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can dynamically remove a driver from a specific device instance through sysfs. This may be a more prudent approach than simply removing the sbridge_edac from the system entirely, as it may be required for other devices. You can also blacklist the driver you dont want through kernel command line.